# Ignore trailing slashes in aiohttp routes

Tags: python, rest, routes, aiohttp

I've been looking in to aiohttp for web services and have run in to an issue with trailing slashes on URLs. If I define a function like so:

```
@routes.get('/global')
async def custom_dict(request: Request) -> Response:
    print(f"Fetching global dictionary...")
    return(web.json_response(request.app['custom_dict']))
```

It will get called by "http://localhost:8080/global", but not with "http://localhost:8080/global/". I know I can add a slash to the route, but then "/global" no longer works. I toyed with the notion of simply having two routes, but that seems redundant.

I also looked at redirects but ran across "merge_slashes" and "append_slashes" and that seems to be the ideal. I've tried several approaches in using them and none have worked so far.

```
@routes.get('/global/', merge_slashes=True)
```

won't even run and

```
@routes.get('/global/')
async def custom_dict(request: Request, merge_slashes=True) -> Response:
```

doesn't seem to do anything.

I have the sense that there's something simple I'm missing, but danged if I can find it. I've searched on Google and tried a few random combinations and so far, no success.

Is there a way to use the route decorators and make the trailing slashes irrelevant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if there is a clean way to do this from reading the docs.

You could create a route regex and handle for trailing slashes or not:

```py
@routes.get("/global{none:[\/]{0,1}}")
async def custom_dict(request: Request) -> Response:
    print(f"Fetching global dictionary...")
    return(web.json_response(request.app['custom_dict']))
```

This is a hack to accept trailing slashes after the path you want to define. It expects a variable that is named `none` and it uses the regex after `:` to parse it.

I am not exactly sure if this covers only the trailing slash case, so if someone can correct me that would be helpful.

Or you can also declare multiple routes for a handler:

```py
@routes.get('/global')
@routes.get('/global/')
async def custom_dict(request: Request) -> Response:
    print(f"Fetching global dictionary...")
    return(web.json_response(request.app['custom_dict']))
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I’m going to try these suggestions and get back to you!! :)

Comment: The specific regex you provided wouldn't work for me, but you got me on the right path, so I accepted the answer.  :)

Here's a list of ones that did work:

@routes.get('/global{none:/?}')
@routes.get('/global{none:\/?}')
@routes.get('/global{none:(\/?)}')
@routes.get('/global{tail:(/?)}')

Possibly others would work as well, but I got what I needed.

Many thanks!!!

Comment: Also, the multiple decorators worked as well.  :)

Thanks again!!!!

Comment: Actually, the regex you provided seems to be working now.....

Comment: Out of curiosity, which docs were you reading....?

Comment: Hey @Robatron , I was reading the latest docs for aiohttp. I just searched for "path" or "route" or something like that. I couldn't find anything about regex in routes, but I found this solution with regex in path variables after reading the server docs. Here they are: https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/web_quickstart.html#variable-resources